# How much long-term damage is typical for professional volleyball to do to your hands?

Tags: volleyball

Do most retired players in their twilight ages have especially twitchy hands or lack of motor control with their fingers? Is it known if volleyball can cause this?

Comment: This seems remarkably specific. Are there known examples of this happening?

Comment: @PhilipKendall This is a completely unscientific speculation.

Comment: This is completely player-specific, AFAIK. Some break fingers even at young age, some don't have so much as a bruise till retirement. Lack of motor control might apply in special cases, I don't know, but is definitely not common. I don't have scientific studies to second that, though.

Comment: While I think it is an interesting question, +1, I don't think there will be much in the way of literature to answer it. Perhaps you should get an MMedSci by answering it, and please share with us the results!